# Django App works on PyCharm by not VS-code (File manage.py line 17 error)

Tags: django, manage.py

I have a Django App that works well in PyCharm. All modules etc work.
I need, however, to open the code in Visual Studio Code.
However, when I execute a:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

command in visual studio code, I get the following error:

```
 File "manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've scoured the resources - but I can't find any solution. I've re-installed python Django using PIP.. - still no luck.
Yes, I've reactivated the VENV - it just so happens it is stuck in activated state - but im ok with that.

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: are you using python 3?

Comment: yes.. but PyCharm works without specifying python3 manage.py...

Comment: so does it work in visual studio code when you run it with python3?

Comment: I just tried 20 mins ago - yes.. but it didn't before. But in PyCharm terminal I don't specify python3...

Comment: You can read more about python environments in VSCode [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to run with `python3`. Your IDE does not know what python interpreter you want to use, so always activate your environment first and check your python with `python --version`. Then run with:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```